# obtaining data from a list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list, windows-forms-designer

I need to get data from a list but orderly mer mean get in the order, but I have this code is not working out.

```
if (item is TextBoxUniversal)
{
    foreach (string i in itemlist)
    {
        ItemValorEntity x = new ItemValorEntity();
        x.Item_Id = i[itemIndex].ToString();
        strItem = x.Item_Id;
        itemIndex += 1;
    }

    txt.Name = item.Name;
    txt = GetTexBox(txt.Name, groupBox1);
    itemValor.Item_Id = strItem;
    itemValor.cClave = Convert.ToString(cboGTTipoItems.SelectedValue);
    itemValor.Valor = txt.Text;
}
```

In a list I have several items can be 101, 102, 103, etc.. I need to get them in order.
That code only managed to get 1 but is not is 1 is 101

Solucionado

```
if (item is TextBoxUniversal)
                {
                    string _item = itemlist[itemIndex].ToString();
                    itemIndex++;

                    txt.Name = item.Name;
                    txt = GetTexBox(txt.Name, groupBox1);
                    itemValor.Item_Id = _item;
                    itemValor.cClave = Convert.ToString(cboGTTipoItems.SelectedValue);
                    itemValor.Valor = txt.Text;
                }
```

Comment: What value in what picture?

Comment: The code doesn't make sense. I don't even see a picture. Is some code missing? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The edit did not help, I still have no idea what you are asking/trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated:

I removed previous answer as I believe this is more what you're looking for.  The ability to sort a list that you've received.  Your question is still poorly asked, so I'm going to go off some assumptions you've implied.  Those are:

- Utilize a hard-coded List.
- Sort the List.
- Display to a user.

The class you'll want to look at for the sort is `List(T).Sort` it provides a clean, quick, and simple approach to accomplish the goal.  Details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I'm going to use a more practical scenario, we have a series of students that will require their score / grades be sorted before output to our user.

To begin will build our `Student` object.

```
public class Student
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Score { get; set; }
     public string Grade { get; set; }
}
```

So far our object is pretty simple, it contains:

- Name (Who it is)
- Actual score (Numeric Representation)
- Grade (Letter Representation)

Now we will implement the `IComparable<Student>` to our `Student` object.  This will implicitly implement the following method:

```
public int CompareTo(Student other)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

So we will remove the `Exception` out of the method and implement:

```
if(other == null)
     return 1;

else
     return this.Score.CompareTo(other.Score);
```

This small amount of code will do the following:

- If the object is `null` it will be greater.
- It will compare our current Property to our Parameter Value.

Now all we have to do for our implementation:

```
// Create Our List
List<Student> student = new List<Student>();

// Add our Students to the List
student.Add(new Student() { Name = "Greg", Score = 100, Grade = "A+" });
student.Add(new Student() { Name = "Kelli", Score = 32, Grade = "F" });
student.Add(new Student() { Name = "Jon", Score = 95, Grade = "A" });
student.Add(new Student() { Name = "Tina", Score = 93, Grade = "A-" });
student.Add(new Student() { Name = "Erik", Score = 82, Grade = "B" });
student.Add(new Student() { Name = "Ashley", Score = 75, Grade = "C" });

// Apply our Sort.
student.Sort();

// Loop through Our List:
foreach (Student placement in student)
     listBox1.Items.Add(placement.Name + " " + placement.Score + " " + placement.Grade);
```

That will put them in a `Ascending` order.  You can tweak and configure to make it `Descending` should you require it, or even more complex.  Hopefully this is a nice starting point.

Also some items have `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` accessible.  So you can actually do code like this to a `Dictionary`.

```
student.OrderByDescending(s => s.Value);
```

You have a slew of possibilities, hopefully this gets you started and able to think about your implementation a bit.

Comment: Hi Greg, I already have that list, what I want is to retrieve those values ​​in an orderly first obtendo the index this one after I get out of index 2 and so on. So I have a variable int decalarada itemIndex = 0; thus be able to add the index and take the next one.

Comment: Already solved thanks